# Scroll doesn't work on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, scroll

For some reason I can't scroll on a website that I am working on. Eventhough u see the scrollbar and u can drag it up and down. It doesn't work with the mousewheel or arrows. This problem is only on chrome on a windows machine. It does work on other browsers and also works on mac.

When I refresh the website with inspector open it does scroll, and when I hold my mouse on a google maps iframe it also scrolls.

Tried to fix it with css, but that didn't work.

Does anyone know what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an origin template from wordpress (Like Twenty xxx) and test it.
If it's work, you've a problem with your own template. If not, re-install Wordpress.